# Image to become smaller when mouse points at it / HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a homepage for my first project in web development and I want to make the images to become smaller when mouse points at them. How can I do this?

Comment: What kind of smaller? I mean do you want it to cause everything below it to move, or not?

Comment: You can use the :hover selector in CSS and apply a custom width on the images.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css `:hover` and the `transform` property to achieve this.

An added bonus with `transform` is that other content underneath the image does not move.

```css
.img {
  transition: transform 350ms ease;
}
.img:hover {
  transform: scale(.75);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img" />

<h2>This is other content underneath the img</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: No problem. Would you mind "accepting" the answer so future people can find the correct answer more quickly?

Comment: Ok, no problem!